# CakePHP 3: How to use custom pagination?

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, paginator

I don't succeed in using the pagination with a custom query. I follow exactly what's in the doc, but it doesn't work. The point is to paginate a list of records, having the flag 'valid' to 'Y' or 'N'.

In the controller:

```
if (!isset($this->request->query['valid']) || $this->request->query['valid'] == '')
  $allFilters['valid'] = 'N';
else
  $allFilters['valid'] = 'Y';
$this->paginate = ['finder' => ['curnames' => $allFilters]];
$data = $this->paginate($this->Names)->toArray();
```

In the model:

```
public $paginate = ['finder' => 'curnames', 'limit' => 25, 'order' => ['Names.id' => 'asc']];

public function findCurnames(Query $query, array $options) {
  $query->where([
    'valid' => $option['valid']
  ]);
  return $query;
}
```

When I execute the code, I get a `Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException` exception. What I am missing?

Update: The version is 3.3. The error is triggered when this is executed:

```
$data = $this->paginate($this->Names)->toArray();
```

Update : In the controller, I've change the line

```
$this->paginate = ['finder' => ['curnames' => $allFilters]];
```

to

```
$paginate = ['finder' => ['curnames' => $allFilters]];
```

and the error doesn't pop up anymore. But the condition filtering on the 'valid'='Y' or 'N' is not taken into account. So it still doesn't work.

Comment: Whenever receiving errors, please always post **the _complete_ error**, that is, **including the _full_ stacktrace** (ideally copied from the logs where it is available in a properly readable fashion), even if the problem might be obvious to people who are familiar with CakePHP! Also show/describe the corresponding context, ie show/highlight the code that actually triggers the error, and please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version - thanks! Often problems even solve themselves when collecting these information.

Comment: Dont do it this way, use a proper PRG pattern based filter approach such as [search](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search). This plugin comes out of the box with a way to do the same thing in less then 3 lines, and you can add tons of more search filters on top later on.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. The error comes from a typo. Correct code should be

```
'valid' => $options['valid']
```

Options with a 's'.
Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier to do something like this (without any custom finder method):

```
if ($this->request->getQuery('valid', '') == '')
  $valid = 'N';
else
  $valid = 'Y';

$this->paginate = [
  'limit' => 25,
  'order' => ['Names.id' => 'asc']
];
$query = $this->Names->find('all')
  ->where([
    'valid' => $valid
  ]);
$data = $this->paginate($query)->toArray();
```